# Premission Denied Bundler|| Parcel

Tags: reactjs, bundler, parcel

`easywork@Pranjals-MacBook-Air foodla % npx parcel index.html Error: Permission denied at Object.open (/Users/easywork/Desktop/foodla/node_modules/lmdb/dist/index.cjs:2530:15) at new LMDBCache (/Users/easywork/Desktop/foodla/node_modules/@parcel/cache/lib/LMDBCache.js:65:34) at resolveOptions (/Users/easywork/Desktop/foodla/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/resolveOptions.js:101:168) at async Parcel._init (/Users/easywork/Desktop/foodla/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Parcel.js:155:27) at async Parcel.watch (/Users/easywork/Desktop/foodla/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Parcel.js:239:7) at async run (/Users/easywork/Desktop/foodla/node_modules/parcel/lib/cli.js:285:9) { code: 13 }`

cleared cache and tried again - didn't work
reinstall parcel - didn't work

Comment: "cleared cache" – how?

Comment: deleted the parcel_cache file